# Why does XPATH is not found on second iteration of for loop

Tags: java, selenium

I am currently doing an automation to check a donut chart and iterate for each color on the donut, There is a functionality where if you hover on the other color, all others will opacity by 30%. So im checking this using a nested for loop.

See below

image[image: donut image]

My problem is that the xpath is not found on the 2nd iteration of the for loop. But when I ma trying to search manually it is trhere and the xpath is correct.

Anyone can see a problem in my code? Thank you in advance.

This is the actual HTML:

```html
<div _ngcontent-c23="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 space-column ng-star-inserted" data-index="0">
        <cws-cardbox _ngcontent-c23="" _nghost-c29="" class="Mutual Funds0" ng-reflect-ng-class="Mutual Funds0" ng-reflect-status="B"><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="card-status overdue" ng-reflect-klass="card-status" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
</div>
<div _ngcontent-c29="" class="card-box">
  
              <div _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy">
                <span _ngcontent-c23="" class="planType" style="display: block;">Mutual Funds</span>
                <span _ngcontent-c23="" class="product" style="display: block;">
                  Affluence Builder Gold
                </span>
                <div _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy-no">
                    <label _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy-label">
                      Account No.:
                    </label>
                    <span _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy-value">8000 0000 03</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div _ngcontent-c23="" class="divider"></div>
              
              <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
              
              <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy-content ng-star-inserted">
                
                <div _ngcontent-c23="" class="invest-mutual">
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div _ngcontent-c23="" class="donut-content ng-star-inserted">
                    <div _ngcontent-c23="" class="donut-main">
                      <mli-donut-chart _ngcontent-c23="" _nghost-c31="" ng-reflect-id="0" ng-reflect-height="226" ng-reflect-width="226" ng-reflect-donut-ratio="0.73444" ng-reflect-raw-data="[object Object]"><div _ngcontent-c31="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
    <div _ngcontent-c31="" class="init-container">
        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div _ngcontent-c31="" class="init-data ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="top: 86.444px; left: 46.0083px; width: 133.983px;">
            <div _ngcontent-c31="" class="init-title">
                Total fund value:
                <div _ngcontent-c31="" class="init-fund-value">
                    <div _ngcontent-c31="" class="init-fund-amt">
                        1M
                    </div>
                    <div _ngcontent-c31="" class="init-fund-curr">
                        &nbsp;HKD 
                    </div>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->        
        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div _ngcontent-c31="" class="mli-donut-chart ng-star-inserted"><svg class="pie mli-donut-chart-svg" width="226" height="226"><g class="mli-donut-chart-graph-main" transform="translate(113,113)"><g><path d="M6.919254415182545e-15,-113A113,113,0,0,1,33.30733470843219,-107.9797270538339L24.462238903260936,-79.30463073741777A82.99172,82.99172,0,0,0,5.0817772126866686e-15,-82.99172Z" fill="#004427" class="mli-donut-chart-arc mli-donut-chart-arc-0" style="fill-opacity: 1; outline: 0px;"></path></g><g><path d="M33.30733470843219,-107.9797270538339A113,113,0,0,1,110.16685407654606,25.144865537063552L80.91094430797848,18.467395045040956A82.99172,82.99172,0,0,0,24.462238903260936,-79.30463073741777Z" fill="#00A758" class="mli-donut-chart-arc mli-donut-chart-arc-1" style="fill-opacity: 1; outline: 0px;"></path></g><g><path d="M110.16685407654606,25.144865537063552A113,113,0,1,1,-2.0757763245547636e-14,-113L-1.5245331638060004e-14,-82.99172A82.99172,82.99172,0,1,0,80.91094430797848,18.467395045040956Z" fill="#5CD790" class="mli-donut-chart-arc mli-donut-chart-arc-2" style="fill-opacity: 1; outline: 0px;"></path></g></g></svg></div>       
    </div>    
</div></mli-donut-chart>
                    </div>
                    <div _ngcontent-c23="" class="donut-fund-date">
                      Fund info as of 1 Mar 2019
                    </div>      
                  </div>
                  
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                </div>
              </div>
        
</div>

</cws-cardbox>
      </div>
```

And this is my script checking it:

```js
public void hoverOverDonutChart(String policyNumber) {

  try {
   
   Thread.sleep(8000);
   DriverUtils.getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
   iGetTotalPolicyCard = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("*//div[contains(@class, 'card-box')]")).size();
   System.out.println("This is the total number of card index: " + iGetTotalPolicyCard);

   if (iGetTotalPolicyCard == 0) {
    Reporter.log("The policy cards are not loaded in the page.", MessageTypes.Fail);
    System.out.println("The policy cards are not loaded in the page.");
    
   }else {
    for(int i = 1; i <= iGetTotalPolicyCard; i++) {
     dataIndex = i - 1;
     
     actualPolicyNumber=DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("*//div[@data-index = '"+ dataIndex +"']/descendant::span[contains(@class, 'policy-value')]")).getText();
     
     if (policyNumber.equals(actualPolicyNumber)) {
      
      Reporter.log("Policy number: "+ policyNumber + " found in Card no.: " + i, MessageTypes.Info);
      System.out.println("Policy number: "+ policyNumber + " found in Card no.: " + i);
      
      DriverUtils.getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      totalNumberOfFund = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("*//div[@data-index = '" + dataIndex + "']/descendant::div//*[contains(@class, 'mli-donut-chart')]//*[contains(@transform,'translate')]//*[contains(@class,'mli-donut-chart')]")).size();
      
      for(int x = 1; x <= totalNumberOfFund; x++) {
      
      System.out.println("x: "+ x + " totalNumberOfFund: " + totalNumberOfFund);
      
      WebElement hoverUnfocus = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Portfolio')]"));
      Actions action= new Actions(DriverUtils.getDriver());
      action.moveToElement(hoverUnfocus).build().perform();
      
      DriverUtils.getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      WebElement fundAllocation = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("(*//div[@data-index = '" + dataIndex + "']/descendant::div//*[contains(@class, 'mli-donut-chart')]//*[contains(@transform,'translate')]//*[contains(@style,'fill-opacity: 1')])["+ x +"]"));
      action.moveToElement(fundAllocation).build().perform();
      Thread.sleep(8000);
      
      Reporter.log("allocation # " + x + " is hovered");
       
       int y=0;
       for(int b = 1; b <= totalNumberOfFund; b++) {
        if(x!=b) {
         y=y+1;
         DriverUtils.getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         WebElement hoveredPortion = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("(*//div[@data-index = '" + dataIndex + "']/descendant::div//*[contains(@class, 'mli-donut-chart')]//*[contains(@transform,'translate')]//*[contains(@style,'fill-opacity: 0.3')])["+ y +"]"));

         if(hoveredPortion!=null) {
          Reporter.log("Passed: allocation #: " + b, MessageTypes.Pass);
         } else {
          Reporter.log("Failed", MessageTypes.Fail);
         }
        }
       }
      }
     break;
     }else {
      if(iGetTotalPolicyCard.equals(i)) {
       Reporter.log("The card with policy number : " + policyNumber + " is not found", MessageTypes.Fail);
      }
     }
    }
   }
   
   
  }catch(Exception e) {
   Reporter.log(e.getMessage(),MessageTypes.Fail);
  }
 }
```

The problem seems to be encountered in the last for loop, because when I comment it out, it works okay without error, it hovered all the items in the donut.

The error occuring in this for loop where on 2nd iteration, xpath is not found.

(This is part of the script - this is the last for loop)

```html
int y=0;
       for(int b = 1; b <= totalNumberOfFund; b++) {
        if(x!=b) {
         y=y+1;
         DriverUtils.getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         WebElement hoveredPortion = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("(*//div[@data-index = '" + dataIndex + "']/descendant::div//*[contains(@class, 'mli-donut-chart')]//*[contains(@transform,'translate')]//*[contains(@style,'fill-opacity: 0.3')])["+ y +"]"));

         if(hoveredPortion!=null) {
          Reporter.log("Passed: allocation #: " + b, MessageTypes.Pass);
         } else {
          Reporter.log("Failed", MessageTypes.Fail);
         }
        }
```

This is the error in the result:

```html
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(*//div[@data-index = '0']/descendant::div//*[contains(@class, 'mli-donut-chart')]//*[contains(@transform,'translate')]//*[contains(@style,'fill-opacity: 0.3')])[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.119)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'PNLCAI731934', ip: '10.242.101.63', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
Driver info: com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb), userDataDir=D:\Users\rosetlu\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir17936_13526}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=72.0.3626.119, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 7eacbc5e38368433e8c6d0c617dfda8a
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=(*//div[@data-index = '0']/descendant::div//*[contains(@class, 'mli-donut-chart')]//*[contains(@transform,'translate')]//*[contains(@style,'fill-opacity: 0.3')])[1]}
```

Comment: Could you provide  stacktrace of your erro/exception?

Comment: I mean when you run your code in IDE/Editor it gives some exception. So could you provide that ?

Comment: I got it ,I just refreshed your question

Comment: (*//div[@data-index = '0']/descendant::div//*[contains(@class, 'mli-donut-chart')]//*[contains(@transform,'translate')]//*[contains(@style,'fill-opacity: 0.3')])[1]

Comment: Doesn't seems a valid xpath to mee, but the error log doesn't mentioned "invalid xpath expression". Still the xpath is weird.

Comment: It is found in the first iteration, the xpath is hard to define because it is autogenerated by mli/angular SPA. In the 2nd iteration xpath is not found but when searching the xpath manually in the browser, it is there and found. I already added waits but still cannot resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to change the object properties and it works now.

i used cssValues instead of checking if object is exists or not.

Below are the changes in the last for...loop.

Thank you for everyone for looking into this issue.

```
                                    //WebElement hoveredPortion = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("(*//div[@data-index = '" + dataIndex + "']/descendant::div//*[contains(@class, 'mli-donut-chart')]//*[contains(@transform,'translate')]//*[contains(@style,'fill-opacity: 0.3')])["+ y +"]"));

                                String notHoveredPortion = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("*//div[@data-index = '"+ dataIndex +"']/descendant::div//*[contains(@class, 'mli-donut-chart')]//*[contains(@transform,'translate')]//*[contains(@style,'fill-opacity')]")).getCssValue("fill-opacity");
                                System.out.println("value of fill-opacity: " +notHoveredPortion);

                                //if(hoveredPortion!=null) {
                                if(notHoveredPortion.equals("0.3")) {
                                    Reporter.log("Passed: allocation #: " + b, MessageTypes.Pass);
                                } else {
                                    Reporter.log("Failed", MessageTypes.Fail);
                                }
```